# can't find idangero.us swiper slider site demo

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, swiper.js

I am trying to use swiper slider for my application. 
[idangero.us](http://idangero.us/swiper/) very beautiful slider but I am not able to find demo code of the slider which is running on site, which is showing features and info of slide.

How to make that slider?I downloaded the source code but in that file demo of the slider which is running on site is not present.

I tried nested slider combining two slider demo codes but not getting results.

Answer (score 0):

Try [downloading the master zip file from swipers github](https://github.com/nolimits4web/Swiper/archive/master.zip) and then open the desired demo inside the \demos folder. From that, you should be able to customize it.

Comment: Yes, I tried that but I thought there would be some demo code of that which is on website

Comment: Maybe you should view-source:http://idangero.us/swiper/ (with your browser) then and copy out the parts of the code you need. Probably the nested divs and the main.js.